# Parsing math rules (with some perks) the same way Soulver (a Mac App) does

Tags: parsing, language-design

[Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver/) is a great scratch pad for math that allows you to write expressions in a very natural form, which makes it versatile and fun to use in many occasions. There's a short video on the site that displays a lot of its functionality.

I'd like to tackle writing a parser that behaved much as that of that app's. For instance, if you go shopping, you can write a big list like

```
2 * 1.99 soap + 2.99 cereal + 39.59 organic magic beans
```

and see, as you type, the sum of what's in the line (46.56).

You can also create variables, such as

```
March = 2 * 1.99 soap + 2.99 cereal + 39.59 organic magic beans
```

and reference them in later operations. Other operators, such as 'off' (40% off $200), also exist.

Considering it has some level of sophistication and it should distinguish meaningful terms while ignoring some of the input, what sort of grammar should I be using to represent this little language? I could probably cobble some spaghetti regex together, but I'd honestly like to do something a little better, even if it requires a lot of study from my part. What would you recommend?

Comment: So, you want `off` to be ignored at times, and at other times want it to be an operator in `X% off Y`?

Comment: That's how Soulver behaves -- off has operator semantics when the preceding term is a percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regexp by itself is likely not expressive enough to the job if you want to model real mathematics, e.g., anything with nested parentheses.

Context-free grammars are remarkably expressive.  You should learn about [Backus Normal Form (BNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), a means for writing down the description of languages as context-free grammars.
You can choose from among many parser generator tools, to convert that grammar into a real parser.

Which specific grammar you write depends on what you want the expressions to mean, and which atoms in the expression really get ignored.
As a practical matter, the way you write the BNF varies from tool to tool, so choosing your parser generator tool first will save you the trouble of rewriting your BNF later.

Comment: That would be a reasonable parser generation/execution tool for doing this. So would virtually all the other tools out there (YACC, JavaCC, ANTLR, ...); expressions (even Soulver's) are not very complicated comparted to modern programming languages, which all of these tools can do.

Comment: Thank you, Ira. I'm going down that path.